# How to navigate to other page using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a onClick function to navigate to other page. I tried this.props.history.push("/SecondPage/ID/") and some examples but nothing worked out.

I have the component like this:

```
export class MainPage extends Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return (
        <div id="main" onClick={this.NavigatetoOtherPage.bind(this)}>
    )
  }  
  NavigatetoOtherPage(){
     let ID = this.props.ID; // I need to pass the ID as a parameter.
      //Here I need to navigate to other page using. I can use window.location.href but I need to use react router.
  }
}
export default connect(state => {
return {
    ID: state.Reducer.ID,       
};
})(MainPage)
```

My app.js file like this

```
export default class App extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>               
            <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage}/>               
            <Route path='/SecondPage/:ID/' component = {SecondPage} />
        </Provider>
    );
}
}
```

My index.js page like this

```
export function renderPage() {  
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('root'));

}
renderPage();
```

How can I navigate to second page without window.location.href

Comment: Do you have any reason for not using <Link> ?

Comment: what should be rendered in the route "/path"? Is your address correct?

Comment: @İlker I can use Link. But How do we use Link in OnClick or OnDoubleClick?

Comment: @alisasani that path is "/SecondPage/ID/".

Comment: Please provide more details. I've created a sandbox link here ( https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-forked-bf13w?file=/index.js) just according to your code,  and as you can see it works fine.

Comment: Did you use BrowserRouter or Router, and Switch?

Comment: @AjeetShah I am using BrowserRouter

Comment: @alisasani It is not working for redux architecture. I have to use connect and provider. Your example is okay but how can we use connect and provider? Mainly the history is not coming in props.

Comment: @alisasani I just updated my index.js page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `useHistory` hook or the `Link` component given you are using react-router-dom

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom";

 // Then in your component
 const MainPage = (props) => {
  /**
   * hooks
   */
  const history = useHistory();

  /**
   * function
   */
  const handleNavigation = () => {
   let ID = props.ID; // I need to pass the ID as a parameter.
  
    history.push(`/dashboard/${ID}`)
  }

  return (
    <button id="main" onClick={() => history.push("/")}> Go to / </button>
    <button id="main" onClick={() => handleNavigation()}> Go to dynamic page 
    </button>
    <Link to={`/dashboard/${props.ID}`} className="some-styling">
      Using Link
    </Link>
  );
};

// I have merged both implementations



export default MainPage;
```

// Edited: Based on the comment, the issue is "The history is not coming in the props."

```
// Then you could use `withRouter` HOC, and then there will be 
// the `history` object in the wrapped component's props.

import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';


class MainPage extends React.Component {

  render(){
    console.log(this.props.history) // history object
    return(<div />)
  }
}

export default withRouter(MainPage)`
```

Comment: I just gave you the sample example. I can't use hooks at this time because my actual file is huge.

Comment: @AshokYaganti I have updated the above based on what you mentioned in the comments about not being able to 'access the history from props'.

Comment: withRouter is worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote down a small sandbox. I guess this is what you are trying to achieve.

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-tereshkova-ilbig?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I tried the same thing. But I don't the history is not coming from props. Is this due to redux connect?

Comment: I have added redux connect. Still works fine. For Demo purpose, I have added dispatch to increment the ID. You can refer to the same link.